# how to Access rest Apis deployed on google cloud /app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an application /rest service deployed on gc using google app engine , i would like to invoke the service from java program locally, I am using token based authentication and i am able to retrieve retrieve the token using google client library , it would be great if i can see some sample invocation code using gc library with auth token

My API end point is something like this

> https://sam-app-dot-new-dev-merge.appspot.com/api/location/workLocationId?workOrderLocationId=950

(I use this url for running the service through postman )

Comment: If you are calling it locally try using it with relative path only. No need to use REST

Answer (score 0):

**Use rest template to internally hit the API and get response from it .**

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 ResponseEntity<?> response= restTemplate.exchange ("https://sam-app-dot-new-dev-merge.appspot.com/api/location/workLocationId?workOrderLocationId=950", HttpMethod.GET, null, Void.class);
```

**You will get whole response from the api in response object.**

Comment: i need to use auth token in call

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question my self

google's  documentation isn't clear(That's me being nice)

before you will be able run this you Need to download gc sdk and configure it see

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;

;

/**
 * 
 * @author sameer.ali
 *
 */
public class AuthenticationManager {

    private  String apiAccessToken  = null;
    private String privateKeyId  = null;

    public  HttpResponse getAuthentication() throws IOException {

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
        apiAccessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
        System.out.println("Token **********" + apiAccessToken);
        credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey();
        privateKeyId = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId();
        System.out.println(" privateKeyId *************" + privateKeyId);
        HttpTransport httpTransport= credential.getTransport();
        HttpRequestFactory httReqFactory= httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://your_url/api/location/workLocationId?workOrderLocationId=9544");
        HttpRequest req = httReqFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        req.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
        HttpResponse response = req.execute();
        System.out.println("service response" + response.getContent().toString());
//      HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer();
//      httpTransport.createRequestFactory(initializer)
//      
        ///new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow().;

        return response;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        AuthenticationManager authM = new AuthenticationManager();
        try{
            HttpResponse response = authM.getAuthentication();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getContent());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String readed;
            while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readed);
            }



//               GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =  return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
//                      getClientCredential(), Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(
//                      DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
//                
        //  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =  return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      String token = authM.getAuthentication();

    }

}
```

ignore code comments

Answer (score 0):

```
gc cloud sdk configuration
```

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\sameer.ali>gcloud -version
```

ERROR: (gcloud) too few arguments
Usage: gcloud [optional flags] 
  group may be           app | auth | components | compute | config |
                         container | dataflow | dataproc | datastore | debug |
                         deployment-manager | dns | iam | ml-engine |
                         organizations | projects | service-management |
                         source | sql | topic
  command may be         docker | feedback | help | info | init | version

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud --help

```
C:\Users\sameer.ali>gcloud -version
```

ERROR: (gcloud) too few arguments
Usage: gcloud [optional flags] 
  group may be           app | auth | components | compute | config |
                         container | dataflow | dataproc | datastore | debug |
                         deployment-manager | dns | iam | ml-engine |
                         organizations | projects | service-management |
                         source | sql | topic
  command may be         docker | feedback | help | info | init | version

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud --help

```
C:\Users\sameer.ali>gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

You do not currently have this command group installed.  Using it
requires the installation of components: [beta]

Restarting command:
  $ gcloud components install beta

Installing component in a new window.

Please re-run this command when installation is complete.
    $ C:\toolkit\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\gcloud.py beta auth application-default login

```
C:\Users\sameer.ali>gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

Your browser has been opened to visit:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=764086051850-6qr4p6gpi6hn506pt8ejuq83di341hur.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&access_type=offline
```

Credentials saved to file: [C:\Users\sameer.ali\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests
Application Default Credentials.

C:\Users\sameer.ali>